# different extend from different applications

Tags: django, django-templates, django-hosts

I'm trying to create one template for all apps, but with different base (related to app).

i'm using django_hosts:

hosts.py:

```
from django_hosts import patterns, host

host_patterns = patterns('',
        host(r'app1', 'app1.urls', name = 'app1'),
        host(r'(app2|application2)','app2.urls', name = 'app2'),
)
```

tree:

```
templates/document.html
app1/templates/app1/base.html
app2/templates/app2/base.html
```

templates/document.html:

```
{% extends base %}
```

And the idea is:

when I go to `http://app1.example.com/document/` i will see `templates/document.html` extended with `app1/templates/app1/base.html`, and if I go to `http://app2.example.com/document/` or `http://application2.example.com/document/` extended with `app2/templates/app2/base.html`

generally it works if I use in

app1/views.py:

```
 (...)
       context={ 'base' : 'app1/base.html' }
    return render(request,'document.html', context)
```

app2/views.py:

```
   (...)
        context={ 'base' : 'app2/base.html' }
    return render(request,'document.html', context)
```

But I want to remove context 'base' from every views' def .

I can't use `app1/context_processors.py` and `app2/context_processors.py`, because it would override themselves, because context_processors are global not app local.

There's an idea:

```
#main/contexts.py
from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve
def appname(request):
    return {'appname': resolve(request.path).app_name}
```

but i don't have urls.py with includes, because i have hosts definition....

Comment: Don't know about Django hosts, but I would extend the default engine and inject another loader that loads base from a host-specific directory or even the database. See here for [details](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-template-backend/).

Comment: @Melvyn I think this is to complex solution. I just need to get name, which is set in django-hosts as name https://django-hosts.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#django_hosts.defaults.patterns

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two approaches:

#### Approach 1

If you just want to make your views less verbose, one thing you could do is create your own `render` function which adds in the appropriate context, you would need to write one of these functions per app. e.g.

```
# app1.views
from django.shortcuts import render as _render

def render(request, template_name, context=None, *args, **kwargs):
    if context is None:
        context = {}
    context = {**context, 'base' : 'app1/base.html'}
    return _render(request, template_name, context, *args, **kwargs)

def some_view(request):
    ....
    return render(request, 'document.html', context)
```

This obviously assumes all your views are in one file, but you could have a `utils.py` for each app, and just import your `render` for that app from the corresponding `utils.py`.

#### Approach 2

Your idea of using a context proccessor, and using resolve could actually work. `resolve` takes an optional argument `urlconf`, and looking at the middleware for django-hosts ([here](https://github.com/jazzband/django-hosts/blob/master/django_hosts/middleware.py#L55))it looks like it sets this on the request, so you could do the following:

```
resolve(request.path, urlconf=request.urlconf).app_name
```

(I've not tested the above, but I can't see why it wouldn't work)

Comment: can't use urlconf, because app_name in classic urls is set in "main" urls.py, where apps urls.py are selected (based on url) and there app_name can be set. But in hosts "main" urls.py is ignored and apps urls.py are selected based on domain regex

Comment: @TomaszBrzezina I'm not sure (and I have never used django-hosts) but having a quick read of the code, it looks like django-hosts actually sets `request.urlconf` to use the appropriate `urls.py` in the correct app.

Comment: yes, but the name is set at include in "main" urls.py, which with hosts is never used

Answer (score 0):

It was easier, than I supposed...

context_processors.py:

```
def appname(request):   
    return {'appname': request.host.name }
```

But 5 hours of searching are lost...